# How to conditionally bind the image source in Angular?

Tags: angular, angularjs

Hello I am getting a response from API with no image source but a name, which I have a collection in my local images folder.

```
 <div class="left">
      <img src="{{ record.imgSrc }}" alt="{{ record.coin }} logo" />
```

how can I conditionally bind the src image based on the name that is based in my local images folder?

Comment: Your question needs more code and information. So how many images could there be?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the curly brackets to display an item, it is not common to put expressions inside them, but it should work:

```
<img src="{{record.imgSrc ? record.imgSrc : record.name}}" alt="{{ record.coin }} logo" />
```

You could also turn the src into a directive with the [] and then put a expression in there:

```
<img [src]="record.imgSrc ? record.imgSrc : record.name" alt="{{ record.coin }} logo" />
```

In either case, the use of the ternary operator for a short hand if statement perfomes the logic.  If imgSrc exists then set img src attribute to the imageSrc value.  Else set the img src attribute to the name value.